# How can I persist data in a docker container on ASP.NET Core app install

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've installed plenty of apps in docker containers where a volume is used to persist data.  I've decided to try and build my own app using .net core 6 and run it in docker.  I currently have the app running in docker and communicating with a SQLite DB.

I'd like the app to have some example data in the DB and on the filesystem after install.

In my app the data is stored in the /files folder and has my database in it.  I tried creating a volume from my host machine to the container in my docker compose file but the data folder in the container is empty after install.  I've found that this is expected because I've mapped an empty host folder to the container, so it overwrote the /files folder in the container.

Do I need to copy the data over when the app starts for the first time or make changes to my Dockerfile to copy the data over after the volume is created?

Any help, examples, or direction would be appreciated.

Below is my docker compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:

 dockertest:
   container_name: dockertest
   image: 192.168.14.2:5500/dockertest:latest
   volumes:
     - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
     - /mnt/data/docker/dockertest/files:/app/files
   ports:
      - "8100:80"
   restart: always
```

Comment: ypu are not creating the SQLite database on the docker compose. I guess you want one and push data on it ?

Comment: No, the DB is already created and wrapped up in my docker image in the folder /files/db.  When I use the volume the /files/db folder is empty.  I simply just want to install the app, have the /files folder be a persistent volume with the database ready to go.  I was thinking maybe I needed to copy the db and the other files I want over to the volume after the install but I'm not completely sure.  Building my own app to run on docker is new to me.

Comment: What is the volume kind?

Comment: It's just a mapping from a folder on the host system to a folder inside the container.